# if we update our database how we add model class in our project in database first approach EF core

Tags: entity-framework

When I add a new table in my database which use in my database first approach EF project I get some error and problem in my project and newly created DB wasn't attached in my project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: After Create Table in Database then open you Package Manager Console**

**Step 2: Use the following Command for add your new table model class**

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Server name;Database=Database name;User
> Id=User name;Password=password;"
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

**Step 3: Hit Enter**

Note: Here only add `-Force` command with previous migration command